# Splitting DataFrame into groups - how to use a windowing function on a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to group non-zero values together, where a group is defined as a sublist of sequential element(s) that contain all non-zero values, segregated by surrounding 0-valued element(s). For example:

```
values = [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 3, 3, 4, 3, 0, 0, 5]
... # do some splitting, grouping, black magic, etc.
values = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 3, 4, 3], [5]]
```

This concept kinda sounds like using a windowing function in PostgreSQL. I'm trying to figure out an efficient/elegant way of doing the same sort of thing with a DataFrame.

I'm working with temporal data, so the resulting groups also need to maintain their original order. For instance, suppose I have the following DataFrame:

```
 timestamp value
2018-01-01     0
2018-01-02     0
2018-01-03     1
2018-01-04     2
2018-01-05     3
2018-01-06     0
2018-01-07     0
2018-01-08     3
2018-01-09     0
2018-01-11     5
2018-01-12     5
2018-01-13     3
2018-01-14     0
2018-01-15     5
```

After splitting it into different groups, I would expect each group to be:

```
# Group 1
2018-01-03     1
2018-01-04     2
2018-01-05     3

# Group 2
2018-01-08     3

# Group 3
2018-01-11     5
2018-01-12     5
2018-01-13     3

# Group 4
2018-01-15     5
```

I've seen similar problems that use an assortment of methods on a DataFrame (`groupby()`, `cumsum()`, `rolling()`, etc.), but nothing that fits my exact needs. I found [this bit of documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) 
that seems to address this type of problem, but came out empty handed. Help, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cumsum` create the group key (PS: I save the result into dict which is more easy for you to get the value)

```
d={x+1 : y[1] for x , y in enumerate(df[df.value.ne(0)].groupby(df.value.eq(0).cumsum()))}
d[1]
    timestamp  value
2  2018-01-03      1
3  2018-01-04      2
4  2018-01-05      3
```

More info

```
for x , y in df[df.value.ne(0)].groupby(df.value.eq(0).cumsum()):
     print(y)

    timestamp  value
2  2018-01-03      1
3  2018-01-04      2
4  2018-01-05      3
    timestamp  value
7  2018-01-08      3
     timestamp  value
9   2018-01-11      5
10  2018-01-12      5
11  2018-01-13      3
     timestamp  value
13  2018-01-15      5
```